# Modifying the genesis block using configtxlator

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm a little confused as to how to modify the system channel configuration once the Fabric network is operational.

I gather that the `configtxlator` tool can be used to create a patch transaction with the necessary changes, but how is this transaction then applied to the system channel?  Can the `peer channel update` CLI tool be used for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [how-to tour](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/configtxupdate/README.md) on reconfiguring the channel with `configtxlator` tool. Basically the high level flow will be:

1. Decode the configuration into json using `configtxlator`.
2. Extract config section
3. Create new configuration
4. Encode both new and old configs
5. Send them to compute the config update delta
6. Decode the config update and wrap up into envelope
7. Produce new config transaction
8. Update channel by submitting new config.

[Here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtxlator.html) is the link for official docs describing reconfiguration flow in details.

And yes you can use `peer` cli tool to update the configuration as following:

```
peer channel update -f config_update_as_envelope.pb -c mychannel -o orderer:7050
```

Comment: I think I understand how a channel configuration can be updated this way, but I'm trying to understand how exactly I could use this tool to modify the orderer system channel, to (for example) add organizations to a consortium, define new consortiums, add org admin users, etc.

Comment: if you need in details explanation, please ask on Rocket.Chat at chat.hyperledger.org.